# No GDB in the new Command Line Tools (OS X Mountain Lion) for Xcode - September 2013?

Tags: macos, xcode, command-line, gcc

I've recently formatted my Mac and when I reinstalled the command line tools, I installed the new  `Command Line Tools (OS X Mountain Lion) for Xcode - September 2013`. I've just typed `gdb` in my terminal to debug one of my programs and it told me `-bash: gdb: command not found`. There is no **gdb** in these new command line tools, is there?

If it doesn't, where can I get it? How can I install it?

Is `brew install gdb` one choice?

Comment: You need to look at lldb - Xcode 5 does not include the GNU compiler or tools

Comment: Why the problem? clang etc are complete C compilers etc

Comment: I have to use it for my CS classes.

Comment: You can get gcc etc but it is complex - if doing a class I doubt the differences between compilers will matter - unless =the class provides C++ libraries but if the class says gcc then it does not aloo Macs - best to ask the teacher

Comment: Also the answer will depend on what you are learning as it will matter how much you know already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple switched to clang/lldb some times ago.

You can still install gdb from brew with `brew install gdb` as suggested. You'll probably want to install gcc with it (you'll have to specify the exact version of `gcc` you want, eg. `brew install gcc47`).

Some privileges are needed for `gdb` to work and you'll need to code sign the binary. See instructions given by brew.

Comment: In other words, you can use `lldb` instead of `gdb`.